# Entity Framework - fields are missing in the table in my Data Model

Tags: entity-framework

I'm relatively new to this stuff.

I created a .Net Entity Data Model, but three fields are missing in one of the tables. I tried creating a new one from scratch, etc.

I can see those fields in the Model Browser(when I expand Tables/Views => tablename), but not in the DataModel.edmx itself.

I'm using SQL DB.

Why can this be happening?
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could they be the Foreign keys into the other tables?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know the types of the fields that are missing.  In any case, I have see situations where I had to drop the table, update the model, then re-add the table and update again.  The EF 1.0 designer is a little buggy.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply! All those missing fields are of type "int", but there is one other "int" field that is not missing. I'll try to drop the table and then re-ad it.

Comment: Unfortunately, dropping the table and re-adding it didn't help.

Comment: Did you update after dropping, then again after re-adding? Also as Leom said, make sure they are not foreign keys.  If they are, they will show up at the bottom of the entity as Navigation Properties.